# Do tvOS transmissions stay active since there is no drain on battery?

Tags: tvos

Two part question:

First, does the Apple TV run app activities in the background while it is asleep? I would assume this would be the case since the Apple TV isn't relying on battery.

Second, if this is not the case, how would I override this keep an app running and writing to my database?

I am building an app that connects to  Bluetooth LE, then writes to a database after connecting. I would like the Apple TV to be the "hub" for my device. So as long as the Apple TV can stay awake, unlike iOS, I should be fine. I could be looking at this the wrong way. Please feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tvOS runs the same application state mechanism that iOS does.  Meaning it has the same old:

`not running > suspended > background > inactive > active`

This also means that it will do basic background processing based on very specific background tasks you specify, just like iOS. Though, tvOS does not have a background data-refresh function, which I'd imagine you'd want to use for the scenario you described.

Check out this Apple doc for more modes. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22

---

To specifically, answer the question: There may be a way to do some background data work, but it would be very limited; And you can prevent sleep programmatically by doing:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

This apple doc will give you all you need to accomplish this.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication

Comment: To be clear, UIBackgroundModes (to which C Jones linked) are currently ***not*** supported by tvOS.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SupportedCapabilities/SupportedCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH38-SW1

Comment: Thank you -- I was mistaken; I was going off the "UIBackgroundModes (Array - iOS, watchOS)" note in other Apple documentation.

Comment: But yes, not all of them are available, for example: background data refresh

Comment: Is it ***just*** `audio` that is supported?  Bottom of: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/

Comment: As far as I know, that is mostly correct for tvOS10 (Audio, AirPlay and Picture in Picture). However, they have stated they are "adding new background modes" for tvOS11.  Unfortunately, i'm not at my desk or i'd look into it :)

Comment: Looks like: (1) Audio, AirPlay, and Picture in Picture, (2) External accessory communication, (3) Background fetch, and (4) Remote notifications